# Is there a way to nest buttons on a custom ribbon split button or flyout?

Tags: ribbon, development

Is there a way to nest controls/buttons under a ribbon split button or flyout?

I have a problem where I need to give some hierarchical representation to the menu items.
For example:

[category 1]
         -- [item 1]
         -- [item 2]
         -- [item 3]
         -- [item 4]

[category 2]
         -- [item 1]
         -- [item 2]
         -- [item 3]
         -- [item 4]

Before the ribbon, in 2007 I used a folder to group the subitems in the menu control on pre-render.

Is there a way of acheiving the same thing with the ribbon?  I have explored but found no way of nesting without breaking the schema, although I did notice that the Format Page gallery under a publishing site gives a nice grouped gallery control but I can't seem to replicate this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DropDown menu, it has Menu items and MenuSection items that can be used to categorize your Ribbon element as you requests.